# why in mysql select time_format(DATE_ADD(time('23:30'), INTERVAL 50 MINUTE), "%k:%i") return is 24:20 not 0:20

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why in mysql this query

```
select time_format(DATE_ADD(time('23:30'), INTERVAL 50 MINUTE), "%k:%i");
```

returning `24:20` instead of `0:20`

whereas in the documentation %k  Hour (0 to 23) ? is bug or missing on my side ?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html
[documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zpfb.png)

Comment: Don't give up reading the manual too early. "If the time value contains an hour part that is greater than 23, the %H and %k hour format specifiers produce a value larger than the usual range of 0..23." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

Comment: What will you do next with the value?  Perhaps "time" is not what you need.